# got "cannot connect to X server" error while training faster rcnn in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, faster-rcnn

I am training faster-rcnn on my custom dataset. I cloned the model from the below github repository :

https://github.com/kbardool/keras-frcnn

After training, while running test-frcnn.py to predict for test images, i got the following error :

**cannot connect to X server**

Here is the screenshot :

[image]

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Such an error normally means tat you're not having a graphical output on the machine that you're running your code on. -> is this a server?
If you're connecting with SSH to the server, use the flags -XY, then this will connect with X-server support.

Comment: I am runing on google colab with gpu support and simply want to predict labels for my test dataset. What could be possibly causing such an error?

Comment: So... this is not on a server, but on your local machine?

Comment: google colab runs in a remote server, that's why it fails.

Answer (score -1):

check your config file add something like daemon=true this will let it running as a daemon server not open Desktop GUI.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).